# Find this cartoon

Tags: knowledge, visual

From the pictures below, can you find the cartoon character?

[image]
[image]
[image]

> EDIT: Edited the 3rd picture for clarity

HINT 1

> A scientist

HINT 2

> Changing from old to new - one word

HINT 3

> Even the highlighted words lead to the answer!!!
>  $$$$
>   [image]

Comment: Just being curious where is the third photo taken?

Comment: Took it from a google search ;)

Comment: Why are people voting to close this? Different people making different (and, frankly, unsatisfying) guesses on a riddle is not at all the same as "multiple answers that fit"—there seems to be ***ample*** room for there to still be an answer that is a vastly better fit than any proffered thus far, so closing this as *too broad* before we've seen the intended solution seems very premature.

Comment: @Rubio Thanks, I just saw your comment. What shall I do now, wait for the answer or give the answer on my own?

Comment: I suggest you wait some more then add more hints.

Comment: @Rubio I went ahead and retracted. Still feeling iffy on this one, but I should give it the benefit of the doubt. We'll see how it pans out and go from there, I guess.

Comment: @jafe At the time I posted my comment (which has now been deleted for some reason), the only tag on the puzzle was "visual"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the beginning I have a feeling of this answer but I don't know how to relate with the first picture.

My guess is, I used to love this cartoon,

> Ben 10

The first picture:

> Mentioned by OP, it means "accelerate" a.k.a "XLR8". Ben can transform to this alien with his omnitrix.

The second picture:

> It's "transform", Ben can transform into 10 (actually more..) aliens. It can also means "upgrade" -- confirmed by OP, one of the alien names.

The third picture:

> The comet, where he gets the omnitrix. May also represents aliens or outerspace tho.

The first clue:

> I also don't know, Ben is not really a scientist, but Benjamin Franklin is.

The second clue:

> Indeed, it is "transform" or "upgrade".

The third clue:

> Man of Action Entertainment is the studio making Ben 10.

Comment: YEP!!! It's correct. Did you see my recent question?

Comment: The first one is just ***accelerate*** (XLR8), second is ***upgrade*** The  scientist is ***Benjamin Franklin***

Comment: @Ak19 actually yes so that's why I may relate that crossword to this question.. tbh I thought about this answer from the start of this puzzle but I couldn't solve the first picture.. But ok then, worthed to try haha ><

Comment: Right, I also thought about **upgrade** too

Answer (score 5):

Spinning a bit further on Udhay's answer, I will try:

> *Star Blazers*, an ABC anime/cartoon show

First image, basically the same reasoning as Udhay:

> The **A**ccelerator, **B**rake and **C**lutch brake pedals point to ABC

Second image

> The *old* seasons where originally released in the early 70ies, while a *new* remake has been made since 2012.

Third image

> Literally an image of a *Star Blaze*.

Comment: Sorry it's not.

Answer (score 5):

Not really satisfied with this answer, but I'll give it a shot.  The character is:

> Captain Comet from DC Comics (also known as simply "Comet"), who was, among other things, an super-intelligent scientist.  Although primarily a comic character, he has appeared in Batman: The Brave and the Bold, making him a cartoon character as well.

First Image:

> Playing off others' answers treating this as Accelerator-Brake-Clutch, or ABC:  Comet's real name is Adam Blake.  Adam-Blake-Comet = ABC

Second Image:

> Per Wikipedia, "he occupies an almost unique position in DC Comics history as a superhero who was created between two great superhero comics periods - the Golden Age and the Silver Age"

Third Image:

> Comet - pretty obvious

Answer (score 4):

I think the answer is:

> **Elroy Jetson**

First image:

> As stated by the other answerers, the first image stands for **A**ccelerator **B**rake **C**lutch (**ABC**) which indicates that the cartoon must be broadcasted by ABC (American Broadcasting Company). **The Jetsons** is broadcasted by ABC.

Second image:

> **The Jetsons** is the *new* counterpart to the *old* **The Flintstones**, as stated in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Jetsons) on The Jetsons: *"It was Hanna-Barbera's Space Age counterpart to The Flintstones."*

Third Image:

> Elroy owns a pet called **Astro**.

Answer (score 3):

Is the answer:(not very sure)

> Professor Triffid in Buzz lightyear of star command

1

> As hinted abc by other answers, buzz lightyear of Star command has been broadcast by abc

2

> Old to new: the characters have taken a new look in the Toy story

3

> Stars and comets: prof. Triffid is a scientist(your hint) who researches on planets. The cartoon series is about space rangers.

Comment: +1 for your answer but sorry but it's not the correct one

Answer (score 2):

I thought answer is based on your hint

> **Dr. Heinz Doofenshmirtz**

First image

> indicates **A**ccelerator **B**rake **C**lutch which is **ABC**. The Mickey Mouse program was first televised for four seasons, from 1955 to 1959, by **ABC**(American Broadcasting Company).

Second image

> indicates Old to New,  Dr. Heinz Doofenshmirtz is Evil Scientist (formerly) and new job is High School Science Teacher. So old to new is **Scientist** to **Science Teacher**

Third Image

> indicates **Disney–ABC Domestic Television**

Comment: You are pretty close in the first line, but sorry it is not correct!

Comment: first line means about ABC or answer

Comment: With the ABC you are pretty close!!!

Answer (score 0):

**partial solution** (attempt)

No clue about the relevance of the first image, but it strikes me that the second image might allude to

> re**nova**tion

while the third image is apparently of a

> **nova** (edit: or a comet, rather. Hmm.)

---

Could be a coincidence, though.

Answer (score 0):

Kinda long shot, but is it

> Robin Hood?

1st photo

> As stated before, **A**ccelerator **B**rake **C**lutch - **ABC Television**

2nd and 3rd photo

> From old to new - re**nova**tion, 3rd photo is a **nova**

All together:

> A show broadcasted by **ABC**, connected to renovations is *Extreme Makeover: Home Edition*, which provides home improvements for less fortunate families
>  Since we are looking for a cartoon character, in relation to *EM:HE* (improving life quality of less fortunate) my guess is **Robin Hood**, who "robbed from the rich and gave to the poor" - meaning he also improved life quality of less fortunate

EDIT/Update:

> About the 1st hint - Scientist
>  [Robyn Williams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robyn_Williams) - Hosted *Science Show* on the **A**ustralian **B**roadcasting **C**orporation

Comment: Sorry it's not. Have a look at the 3rd hint :)