# Can you guess the character I am thinking of?

Tags: knowledge

Inspired by [this puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/84227/find-this-cartoon/), I decided to make my own guess-my-character puzzle. The only different thing is that mine isn't based on images. This is the first time I'm making a puzzle, so here's my try:

### 1 – I start with:

- I am not a girl.
- I'm not considered intelligent.
- I don't like cake.
- I don't sell houses.
- I don't really eXist.
- I don't have a long name.
- I'm not linked to horse-riding.
- I haven't played in 'Titanic'.
- I don't use a shield.
- I don't have over 1000 subscribers.
- I don't like Redstone.
- I don't bake cookies.
- I don't have a dark sense of humour.
- I'm not from Dangermouse.
- I'm neither under 27 nor over 40 years old.
- I don't use Funimate.
- I'm not a parent.
- I don't hold a world record.
- I don't have claws.
- I don't like to tell stories.
- I'm not a doctor.
- I'm not from a chinese dynasty.
- I'm not a Time Lord.
- I'm not under 5 foot 6.
- I'm not known for playing Animal Jam.
- I'm not made out of metal.
- I'm not going to live in Chelsea.
- I don't use a metal suit.
- I'm not a part of a two-person team.
- I don't wear heavy make-up.
- I'm not linked with speed.
- I'm not from KanCollee.
- I don't fight against monsters.
- I'm not a queen.
- I'm not a soccer player.
- I don't always hide my eyes.
- I don't work with children.
- I don't write books for children.
- I didn't win a briefcase at Money in the Bank.
- I didn't kidnap a princess.
- I'm not from a roleplay server.
- I'm not an animatronic fox.
- I don't have robotic parts.
- I don't have green skin.
- I don't have a tail.
- I don't wear a cape.
- I don't go to school.
- I don't use guns.
- I'm from a TV series.
- I'm not evil.
- I'm not scary.
- I'm not linked to Vsauce.
- I'm not transgender.
- I wasn't created by HeylmBee.
- I have a dark hair.
- I'm not from The Flash.
- I'm not linKed with an insect.
- I'm American.
- I'm not from the 'Halo' franchise.
- I've been in a superhero movie.
- I'm not from The Rocky Horror Picture Show.
- I don't have smoke power.
- I've never been on Dance Academy.
- I wasn't popular in the 90's.
- I didn't die a natural death.
- I don't wear blue clothes.
- I don't play NLR.
- I'm not linked with drugs.
- I often wear sunglasses.
- I never won a Winbledon.
- I didn't partiCipate in a Holy Grail War.
- I'm physically impaired.
- I'm not an X-Men.
- I can't become invisible.
- I don't have a sword.
- I don't wear a lot of black.
- I'm not a bully.
- I'm not from Gravity Falls.
- I'm not related to Pokémon.
- I have human skin.
- I don't have multiple albums.
- I'm not a rapist.
- I'm not a part of PVRIS.
- I don't have a tattoo sleeve.
- I don't live in the Australian bush.
- I don't have Jewish origins.
- I'm not linked to alcohol.
- I'm not a dress designer.
- I don't play Crash Bandicoot.
- I don't live in the North Pole.
- I can't fly.
- I don't talk to animals.
- I don't live in a palace.
- I'm not associated with water.
- I'm not in the Mighty Bush.
- I don't have a pug.

### 2:

I'm in a crisscross, a griD, a filigree, a trellis or something like that.

### 3:

I like visiting a place like the one in 683.

---

**HINT 1:**

> If you're wondering why *so many* affirmations in the first clue, it's because they've been extracted from multiple [Akinator](https://en.akinator.com/) plays for the same character. Some key affirmations were hidden on purpose, but use the ones provided here and Akinator will give you *very strong* hints about the character mentioned in this clue. It isn't guaranteed that Akinator will guess the right character only with the affirmations provided here, though. You'll have to fill in the blanks. Frankly, you might guess who it is without even using Akinator at all.
>
>  The affirmations written here are based on what Akinator *expects* you to answer about the character (shown in the game summary after the game finishes). This might not be what *you* expect, and some affirmations might even be misleading, although, for Akinator, they aren't. Plus, I must've played hundreds of times now, and it's *absolutely guaranteed* that Akinator *will start* to make the *right questions* about the specific character in the first clue. The right question usually appears between the 6th and 8th question.

**HINT 2:**

> I don't know about you guys, but for me, Akinator keeps *whining* about the character being mostly **red** and **wearing a mask**. Are these the *right questions*?
>
>  [image: Is he masked?]
>
>  [image: Is he mostly red?]

**HINT 3:**

> W*H*at *I*s so stra*N*ge abou*T* those word*S*?

**HINT 4:**

> Dial 'M' for MORE HINTS!

**HINT 5:**

> You cannot see air but you know it exists!

**HINT 6:**

> Take a look at the dictionary... *or something like that*.

**HINT 7:**

> I have a pretty smart brother.

**HINT 8:**

> There's a reason why there's a short description in the first clue.

**HINT 9:**

> I'm a *cartoon*!

**HINT 10:**

> *Ooooooooh... what does this button do?*

---

As an off-topic, I'd like to hear from you what you think about this puzzle, as it's my first one. Every constructive criticism and helpful suggestions are welcome!

Comment: I'm not under 27 neither over 40 years old. --> I'm neither under 27 nor over 40 years old?

Answer (score 1):

## Partial Answer

So, I started to use the Akinator, and

> That went nowhere.

Here's my line of thought:

> Start with the clues that talk about what the character *is*, not what the character is not. These clues will hold more information.

Here they are:

> I'm from a TV series. 
>  I have human skin. 
>  I'm American. 
>  I have a dark hair 
>  I've been in a superhero movie. (Likely DC or Marvel character) 
>  I'm physically impaired. 
>  I often wear sunglasses. (possibly blind?)

That's pretty good! Now on to some other info I think is helpful:

> I am not a girl. 
>  I'm not considered intelligent. 
>  I can't fly. 
>  I haven't been in something produced by the Disney Company. (***HUGE clue*** - this is not a Marvel character).

At this point, I feel like I need to know more about the

> DC Comics

to proceed further. If anyone with this knowledge would like to proceed based on this answer, go on ahead.

Comment: Akinator _will_ lead you nowhere 99% of the time if you try to answer him using only the affirmations provided here. If you do some deduction (like the one you made about the sunglasses) you'll easily get to the answer, as Akinator will start to make the right questions.

Comment: I've removed the Disney Company affirmation because Akinator's expected answer is misleading. Although there are _other_ misleading expected answers, this is by far the most misleading one.

Comment: @PedroCorso that's both concerning and relieving lol - not sure which one, yet.

Answer (score 1):

## Observations adding on to Brandon_J

First of all, I noticed that

> Capital letters that seem out-of-place spell XKCD. XKCD 683 takes place in *some sort of lab.* However, the character isn't a doctor, so they might be a scientist. Then  again, they aren't considered intelligent.

One useful observation is that

> the character is also from a TV show.

Also, there are these things the character doesn't have:

> doesn't use a shield or a metal suit 
>  not considered intelligent 
>  doesn't use guns or robotic parts 
>  doesn't have a cape 
>  not linked to speed 
>  can't fly 
>  can't become invisible 
>  etc...

This seems to imply that the character is

> not a superhero (since they don't seem to have any physical or mental superpowers) but just a supporting character.

One last thing:

> "I didn't die a natural death" may imply that the character died-- I don't think Akinator would ask about how the character died without knowing that he died...

Comment: Nice job catching the 683 reference.

Comment: +1 for getting the 3rd clue right!

Answer (score 1):

You are:

> Daredevil, a.k.a. Matt Murdock, from Marvel Comics

There are too many clues to explain them all, but a few of the key clues are:

> Daredevil is a superhero with a TV series (on Netflix) as well as a theatrical movie.  He is blind ("I often wear sunglasses" and "I'm physically impaired"). He does not have the superpowers listed ("claws", "become invisible", "robotic parts", "smoke power", ...) and does not wear a cape. He did die recently in the comics, but apparently is coming back (typical for comics) so "I didn't die a natural death" could also fit.)

Comment: +1 For the right answer... for the **first clue**. :)

Comment: So clues 2 and 3 relate to something completely different that then combine for a single final answer?  That makes sense, but I completely missed that part of the puzzle.  But it does explain why I couldn't make my answer fit clues 2 or 3 at all ...

Answer (score 0):

Although I have no confidence that this is indeed the answer, but in my opinion the answer is:

> **Steve Rogers** ( Captain America is the alter ego of him).

What made me think that way was mostly us:

> Steve Rogers was born on July 4, 1918, on the Lower East Side in Manhattan, New York looking high and gaunt- **I am not a girl**.

---

> Concerned about the rise of the Third Reich to power-**I don't have Jewish origins**(Some will think that only a Jewish person will have to worry about it (which of course is not true)).

---

> Steve tried to enlist in the American army but was rejected due to its physical characteristics-**I'm physically impaired**.

---

> At the end of April 1945, in the final days of World War II, Captain America and Bucky try to stop their opponent Baron from plotting to destroy an unmanned pilot aircraft. Zamo sends the plane with a bomb on it when Rogers and Bucky follow. They manage to get on the plane before taking off, but when Bucky tries to neutralize the bomb, it explodes when the plane is in the air. The boy is considered dead, and Rogers falls into the icy ocean. No body is revealed and both are considered dead. In retrospect it was learned that none of them had been killed-**1945-1918=27**-**I'm neither under 27 nor over 40 years old.**-(What he says is sure he's older than 27).

---

> Captain America has no superpower, though thanks to the "super-soldier" serum combined with the Vita rays treatment, he is transformed from a lean young man into the most perfect specimen of human development. The levels of strength, endurance, agility, speed, along with the reflexes and healing abilities of Captain America are among the highest and are at the peak of human efficiency.**I have human skin.I don't have green skin.I don't have a tail.I can't fly.I don't talk to animals.I don't have smoke power.**

---

> In 1966, Captain America appeared in an animated series called "Marvel Heroes" along with characters like Iron Man, Thor, The Green Giant and the Submariner in stories based on the series of booklets at the time.Captain America also appeared in the animated series of Spider-Man and the X-Men of the 80's and 90's. In 2010 the character appears alongside other superheroes in the Hawkers: the animated series based on the Evangelists.- **I'm from a TV series**.(**I'm not an X-Men.**)

---

I did not relate to all the sentences because some of them are understandable from the answer for example:**I don't have a long name.**

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not the answer. See the first hint.

Comment: @PedroCorso Thanks for the reference, and welcome to Puzzling StackExchange (Also congratulations on your riddle )

Comment: also "I don't use a shield." is a little iffy.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you are:

> Plastic Man -- I'm not sure how to insert a full-sized [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTFRS.png) in a spoiler.

He fits because:

> He has dark hair, is male, doesn't wear blue (wears red), appears in cartoon tv shows and a few animated super hero movies. All the movies he's appeared in has been post 2000. Sunglasses are part of his costume, technically he's physically impaired because he is now made out of plastic. He still looks like he has human skin though. He is not evil, he's a superhero. He isn't the sharpest tool in the shed. He didn't die an unnatural death because he's actually alive and essentially immortal. He looks between 27 and 40, he is a DC character. And it fits all of the rest of the requirements as well.

Other hints:

> Thanks to @ev3commander for figuring out the XKCD 683, that it something that relates to a lab. Plastic man used to be a crook and he planned to rob a lab and got doused by a chemical vat.

Comment: I think you're stretching the meaning of "physically impaired" here. Not to mention that _looking_ like having a human skin isn't really _having_ a human skin. But nice try!